# How to display an array horizontally without mentioning all the numbers and break tag?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```js
 var days = [
   "Monday",
   "Tuesday",
   "Wednesday",
   "Thursday",
   "Friday",
   "Saturday",
   "Sunday",
 ];
         
 document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = days[0] + "<br>" +
                                              days[1] + "<br>" +
                                              days[2] + "<br>" +
                                              days[3] + "<br>" +
                                              days[4] + "<br>" +
                                              days[5] + "<br>" + days[6];
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
            
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
}
            
table tr td {
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Concatenation Challenge</h1>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>All days of the week</td>
     <td id="demo2"></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Hi, this sounds like a weird question. Is there a way to display from [0] to [6] without mentioning in-between numbers(1-5)? I tried for loop but I don't think I am doing it right. for (var i=0;i > days.length;i++);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.join()`:

```
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = days.join("<br>");
```

**Demo:**

```js
var days = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday",
];
         
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = days.join("<br>");
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

table {
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    margin:5px;
}

table tr td{
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Concatenation Challenge</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>All days of the week</td>
        <td id="demo2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var days = [
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday",
                "Sunday",
            ]
            // From HERE
            var myString = "";
            
            for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {

               myString = myString + days[i] + "<br>";
             }
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = myString;
            // TO HERE
```

```css
          body {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            
            table {
                border:1px solid #000;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width:500px;
                height:150px;
                margin:5px;
            }
            
            table tr td{
                border:1px solid #000;
                padding-left:10px;
            }
```

```html
        <h1>Concatenation Challenge</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>All days of the week</td>
                <td id="demo2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: ` myString = myString +` can be written as ` myString += ...` It reduces typing and keeps code clear

Comment: That was what I tried to do...forgot to do the second part haha...Thank you!